# Should I use UI image or sprite Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I am making a castle wall and right now I am using a square for the wall and 3 capsules for the "empty" spaces. Because they're the same color as the background. Is this a proper way of approaching this or should I use UI images, make them transparent at those spots and put box colliders around them? For me it's easier and faster with the sprites but maybe it is more efficient with images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6xsK.png)

Wall is a square on layer 0, capsule is on layer 1 and the square representing the ground is on layer 2 so it can hide the last part of the cylinder. Is there some more efficient way you could recommend me to use? Thank you.

Comment: When u say sprite, do you mean sprite renderer vs ui image? Sprite is a class for an image, it's not a component. Sprite renderer renders a sprite in the scene, ui image renders a sprite in UI. So choosing one or the other is about where is your castle, in the scene or the UI?

Comment: Yes I mean 2D object > sprite > And one from the section. So yes sprite renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImage is a UI element that exists on a Canvas. UIImage is best used as a part of the user interface (UI), e.g. Buttons, overlays and so on.

In your case, the castle is an object in the game world, so it is better to use Sprite Renderer, as the other objects in the game will probably exist in the game space, not UI space, as well.